# Why does .catch() not catch reject() within Promise constructor within loop at an async function unless Error is passed?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Given

```js
(async () => {
 const p = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error(1))
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))); return p})()
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the `Error()` is logged at `.catch()`

If we extend the pattern to use a loop the `Error` is logged at `.catch()`

```js
const fn = async(res, ...props) => {
  for (let prop of props) res.push(await prop())
  return res
}

const arr = [
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      setTimeout(() =>
        reject(new Error(1))
      , Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    ),
  () => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      setTimeout(() => 
        resolve(1) 
      , Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    )
  ];

fn([], ...arr)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

If we use a loop to call more than one function which returns a `Promise` and do not explicitly pass `Error()` to `reject()` of `Promise` constructor `resolver` function `.catch()` does not catch the error, and array `res` is not returned, only the `Promise` value passed to `resolve()` is available at

```js
const fn = async(res, ...props) => {
  for (let prop of props) res.push(await prop())
  return res
}

const arr = [
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      setTimeout(() =>
        reject(1)
      , Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    ),
  () => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      setTimeout(() => 
        resolve(1) 
      , Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    )
  ];

fn([], ...arr)
// what happened to our array `res` returned from `fn`?
.then(data => console.log(data))
// what happened to our rejected Promise?
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Questions:

1. Why does `reject()` call not propagate to `.catch()` when `Error()` is not explicitly passed to `reject()` within `Promise` constructor within a loop at an `async` function?
2. Why is only a single `Promise` value returned to `.then()` though an array is returned from the `async` function when one of the `Promise` objects iterated at a loop `reject()` function is called within `Promise` constructor `resolver` function?

Comment: `fn` throws with the first iterations `await prop()` ... hence why the last catch outputs the `1` (it's the last catch that is called, not the last then)

Comment: @JaromandaX A good reason to use `console.error()` instead of `console.log()` at `.catch()`. Can you post your comment as an Answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If we […] do not explicitly pass `Error()` to `reject()` of Promise constructor resolver function `.catch()` does not catch the error

Sure, because there is no Error then. But `catch` will catch whatever you pass to  `reject`, which is the value `1`, which does get logged correctly.

Comment: The issue was user error in reading the response. To prevent the user error in the future: 1) explicitly pass `Error()` when and error is expected, and 2) use `console.error()` instead of `console.log()` at `.catch()` to distinguish resolve and rejected `Promise` value where the values might happen to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When trying code, for example where `Promise` is used, and an error is expected to be logged at `.catch()`, explicitly pass `Error()`, preferably with a relevant message as parameter, to `reject()` of `Promise` constructor  or `Promise.reject()`; and substitute using `console.error()` for `console.log()` at `.catch()`, for the purpose of distinguishing the error that you are expecting to be logged as an `Error()` and not a resolved `Promise` value, where the resolved and rejected value may happen to be the same.